# php - passing array from functions file to page

Tags: php, arrays, parameter-passing

I need to pass an array from the functions.php(this is not a html page, just a functions file) file to a page file. Even better to popupwindow if possible...

I did it as:

1) Set Session in functions.php as

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }
?>
```

2) Create a session var and assign values. Forward to the endpage

```
$_SESSION['array'] = $nodes;
header("Location: endpage.php");
```

3) Read session var and do some job...

```
<?php 
session_start();

$tim[] = $_SESSION['array'];

    foreach ($tim as $result) {
        echo $result['val'];

    }

?>
```

It doesnt work, the array is empty...

Comment: Tried `$tim = $_SESSION['array']`?

Comment: wat do u ve in $nodes?

Comment: @kingkero i posted the same code above but id doesnt works

Comment: @Nabin in nodes are amoe values, its not empty

Comment: then what do yo get when u do var_dump($_SESSION['array'])??

Comment: in functions.php i got
array(5) { [0]=> string(58) "http://www.image.com/opena/1234567/1234567/cache/image.jpg" [1]=> string(58) "http://www.image.com/opena/1234567/1234567/cache/image.jpg" [2]=> string(58) "http://www.image.com/opena/1234567/1234567/cache/image.jpg" [3]=> string(58) "http://www.image.com/opena/1234567/1234567/cache/image.jpg" [4]=> string(58) "http://www.image.com/opena/1234567/1234567/cache/image.jpg" } array(0) { } array(0) { } 

but in endpage i got array(0) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is actually data in the $_SESSION['array'] ! Try this

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    foreach ($_SESSION['array'] as $result) {
        echo $result['val'];

    }
?>
```